# Cannot find module "@auth0/angular-jwt/"

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, auth0

I'm currently developing a Web Application using ADFS authentication.

I have the following runtime error:

> "Cannot find module @auth0/angular-jwt".

I'm using **Angular 5.2.10**. I've tried to reinstalled my dependencies, however I still have errors:

I've errors in `index.d.ts`:

> Cannot find name 'Provider'and 'ModuleWithProviders'

And in `jwt.interceptor.d.ts`:

> Cannot find modules "@angular/common/http" and "rxjs/internal/Observable"

And in `jwtoptions.token.d.ts`:

> Cannot find module "@angular/core"

I haven't modified any of those files.

Is this an angular version problem? Am I using wrong versions of those libraries?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder
2. Run `npm i`

Try running it again

Comment: I had the same problem with a Vue 3 app. This also helped me. In case it wasn't obvious, it also works for other JS frameworks, not just Angular.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed all the dependency required for “@auth0/angular-jwt/”
,

**Basically the bellow solution works for all error saying " *Cannot find module*"**

1. first install required dependency  ( here you should install  *npm i @auth0/angular-jwt*
2. restart the project

and if still shows the same error then

1. Delete your node_modules folder
2. Run npm i

Answer (score 2):

Answering for your first query i.e **Cannot find module @auth0/angular-jwt"**

Make sure inside **node_modules** folder you have specified path :- **@auth0/angular-jwt/src/**

## If yes then use

`import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt/src/jwthelper.service';`

## if no then first run installation with npm or yarn

```
npm install @auth0/angular-jwt
 
# installation with yarn 
yarn add @auth0/angular-jwt
```

Answer (score 1):

The error messages of the following format:

> Cannot find module `<module>`

indicates that a ***necessary dependency for your project is unmet*** and needs to be installed or re-installed if the prior installation had an issue downloading the necessary library.

Perhaps you can try the following and seeing if it helps:

1. Remove your `package-lock.json` file to ensure there are no locking issues for dependencies. **Note**: this file will be auto-generated

   `rm package-lock.json`
2. Delete your previous `node_modules` directory

   `rm -rf node_modules`
3. Re-install your dependencies listed in your `package.json` file

   `npm i` or `yarn install`
4. If you still get complaints about missing modules try **installing and saving** the necessary dependency into your `package.json` file

for example,

> Cannot find module @auth0/angular-jwt".

```
npm i @auth0/angular-jwt
```

5. **Double check dependencies for version compatibility**. For example, `@auth0/angular-jwt` **v2** is to be used with **Angular v6+ and RxJS v6+**. For Angular v4.3 to **v5+, use `@auth0/angular-jwt` v1**. I see you mentioned you're using `Angular 5.2.10.` so make sure your're using **version 1** of the `@auth0/angular-jwt` library.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have installed @auth0/angular-jwt on the correct node_modules. That solved my problem. It is a typical dependency error.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is no auth folder in node modules.. Please check its present or not.
Run npm install and restart the project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30098567)

Comment: Thanks @Varsha Bisht Your answer was very helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple like put this in the console:

npm i @auth0/angular-jwt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late but for anyone encountering the same issue, make sure you imported the `JwtModule` in your app.module or feature module, and then in your authentication service you can just use:

`import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';`

Code example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // Check whether the token is expired and return
    // true or false
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
}
```